# Python elif invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make this elif statement but it keeps showing me this error "invalid syntax"
can someone explains this for me and thanks!!!

Code:

```
x = int(input("Hello, how old are you? "))
y, u, i, o, p, l, b, c, v = 0, 12, 13, 19, 20, 30, 31, 64, 65
try:
    x == int
    if y < x <= u:
        print("Kid")
    elif:
        i < x <= o
        print("Teenager")   
    elif:
        p < x <= l
        print("Young Adult")  
    elif:
        b < x <= c
        print("Adult")  
    else:
        print("Senior")
except:
    print("Is that an age?")
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-15-6032d446949e>", line 7
    elif:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `el`**`IF`** ... needs a condition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements), `elif` should be used like:

```py
try:
    if y < x <= u:
        print("Kid")
    elif i < x <= o:
        print("Teenager")
    elif p < x <= l:
        print("Young Adult")
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have implemented wrong syntax here is a correct syntax of `if..elif..else`

```
if(condition):
   statement
elif(condition):
   statement
```

and here is your complete code

```
x = int(input("Hello, how old are you? "))
y, u, i, o, p, l, b, c, v = 0, 12, 13, 19, 20, 30, 31, 64, 65

try:
        x == int
        if y < x <= u:
                print("Kid")
        elif i < x <= o:
                print("Teenager")
        elif p < x <= l:
                print("Young Adult")
        elif b < x <= c:
                print("Adult")
        else:
                print("Senior")
except:
    print("Is that an age?")
```